# why does "npm install <module>" keep rebuilding other unrelated modules?

Tags: node.js

I've got some modules in my node_modules directory that require length compilation to build.  But whenever I go to install some simple, unrelated module, I see it re-building these modules as well!  Why is it doing this, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Are those rebuilt modules some dependancies of the module you're trying to install?

Comment: @Adriano no, they are complicated database stuff and i'm trying to install various simple file utilities which have nothing to do with databases